# Django Built In Admin Throws "int object is not subscriptable" Error When Adding Object

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a simple django app using django 1.6 and python 2.7.2 and I wanted to create a `Post` object quickly so I could test something else I was writing. Used the built in django Admin page to add the object, and it threw an error saying `'int' object is not subscriptable`. I'm sure I could create the object in another way if necessary, but I am wondering if this is something I am doing incorrectly that I should fix or if it is a bug I shouldn't worry about.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Forum(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, blank = True)
    public = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Thread(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    can_post = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.id

class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Like, blank = True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  430.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  339.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1131.                 self.log_addition(request, new_object)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in log_addition
  598.             action_flag=ADDITION
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/models.py" in log_action
  19.         e = self.model(None, None, user_id, content_type_id, smart_text(object_id), object_repr[:200], action_flag, change_message)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/forums/post/add/
Exception Value: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the __unicode__ method of the Post class to return unicode(self.id)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to return:

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.id
```

instead of

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

in the Post class

Python expects you to return a unicode string, but you are returning an int here.

You can also just return `unicode(self.id)`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. I figured i was doing something stupid.

Comment: Glad it works. Yes, especially cause we think that in Python, return an int as a string works, as it is not statically typed, but unicode is different ;)